# VB.6 пропадает отрисовка формы. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vb6

При запуске самой визуал студии на Windows 7, редактор создания формы жутко лагает при перемещении компонентов, эта проблема решается Отключением композиции рабочего стола в настройках совместимости.
Написанная программа так же выполняется очень медленно в моменты когда происходит отрисовка в PictureBox и при чтении точек из контрола. 
Отключив композицию рабочего стола в свойствах ярлыка производительность программы увеличивается более чем в 20 раз, но основная проблема не в лагах.
Через какое то время работы программы прекращается отрисовка, при том что работа программы не прекращается и элементы формы реагируют на события. При перемещении или разворачивании формы она становится невидимой или залитой белым цветом.
На ХР все работает корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Форма стала не видимой пришлось поводить над ней окном браузера]

Даже если отправите меня в гугл, но при этом подскажите более конкретное направление буду премного благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Сам юзаю VB6 в седьмых форточках

Могу посоветовать для форм изменить autoredraw (или создать 2 проги с true и с false), если это ещё не было сделано. И посмотреть на результат (чтобы чуть данными вопрос дополнить). Хотя, 
то уже "костыль" в своём роде... Но может пролить частичку света в вопрос.

Также посмотреть компоненты Visual C redistributable версий от 2005, может ещё 2008 (не точно).

Нужны версии х32. Если система стоит х64, то х32 и х64.

По идее IDE и программы должны запускаться и работать корректно без выставлений каких-либо совместимостей. Что наталкивает на определённые мысли.

Попробуйте найти форум про VB6, в котором выкладывают свои программы, скачайте и погляньте результат. Если они тоже будут так себя вести - проблема в форточниках, иначе в самом компиляторе/студии.

Ещё вариант - установка самой студии. Возможно где-то что-то не ладно.

Ответить более детально не смогу, случаев подобных не нагуглил, нету.

Дополненице: у меня стоит 6.12, лицензия... Ходят слухи, что версии старше (т.е. 6.0 и ранее) могут некорректно работать под форточками младше Vista (и далее, до 10-ки)... Но это не точно.

Есть такой вариант - портативную версию поставить. В системные файлы не лезет что-то "затирать" и вставлять. Это если проблема в системных файлах.

Или поискать (если не лицензия с диска, а пиратка в т.ч. с образа диска) другой дистрибутив, но это уже, скорее, один из последних шагов.

Если ничего из этого не поможет, то перед паникой со сносом форточек стоит попробовать установить на виртуалку с 7-ми форточками, или другой компьютер (для тестов). Например у друга попросить, либо на работе втихаря (но потом удалить все следы установки, на всякий) и поглянуть работоспособность там.

Вопрос вроде-бы и довольно конкретно изложен, но учитывая нетипичность ситуации сказать трудно. Дело однозначно в системе графического вывода (либо компонентах DirectDraw, нативного "рисования", либо дровишках показульки-видюльки), на что намекает "отключение композиции рабочего стола"... Хотя, если другие программы нормально работают (в вопросе не написано), то что-то "тормозит" программу получать драгоценные ресурсы системы вывода графики...

И последнее - АнтивирЪ. Есть вероятность, что дело в его "слежении" за самой студией и выплёвываемыми ей программками. Перепроверьте систему (на всякий) - если чисто - рубите минут на 5-10, хватит, чтобы запустить программу, а потом студию и посмотреть на результат.

Сказать что-то более конкретное сложно - мало данных...

Comment: Кстати, никакие "сторонние" компоненты отрисовки не используете?